# Would writing a decision tree algorithm in Pytorch or Tensorflow be faster than with Numpy?

Tags: tensorflow, decision-trees, pytorch, numpy, parallel

Since these libraries can turn CPU arrays into GPU tensors, could you parallelize (and therefore accelerate) the calculations for a decision tree? I am considering making a decision tree class written in Tensorflow/Pytorch for a school project, but I want to be certain that it makes sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly, mostly because the structure of a decision tree doesn't lend itself to GPU parallelisation, and is better suited to CPUs. Even the most established decision tree algorithms use CPUs.

- GPUs can only perform a small subset of operations at high performance, the most important being matrix multiplication, which is the fundamental building block of a neural network.
- Decision trees don't train by gradient descent, but an iterative process of partitioning the dataset. As such, they need access to the entire dataset in memory (rather than batches).
- Decision trees are not easily differentiable without amendment.

The Deep Neural Decision Forest paper *does* address these issues in a simple and clever way:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/ICCV15_DeepNDF_main.pdf

This is interesting as it does allow trees to be learnt with gradient descent, but it's unlikely to be faster than existing CPU bound tree algorithms.